# When I see a bunch of `write: broken pipe ` errors for a process what does it mean ?

Tags: linux, docker, socket

When I see a bunch of `write: broken pipe` errors for a process what does it mean ?

`level=error msg="attach: stdout: write unix /var/run/docker.sock->@: write: broken pipe"`

Does this mean this process needs more file descriptors ? or any other resource ? which way should I be looking at ?

Comment: usually it means `someprogram` in a `program | someprogram` type of pipe has gone away while `program` was writing to that pipe

Answer (score 5):

It means that someone has set the signal handler for `SIGPIPE` to `SIG_IGN` (ignore), and the error (trying to write into a pipe with no reader) is reported instead via the exit status of `write(2)`.

In your case, the program at the other end of the Unix socket is most probably crashing or exiting unexpectedly. I'll look first into that.

It *may be* some sophisticated attack -- many badly written programs don't expect errors from `write(2)` and do not check its return value.

A process exiting because of a `SIGPIPE` is nothing special, and it's how things should work. This is how `command | head -5` works; if `command` still wants to write stuff into the pipeline after `head -5` has exited, it will receive a `SIGPIPE`, and everything will finely terminate. But if command installs a signal handler for `SIGPIPE`, or if the calling shell has set a `trap '' PIPE` (which will cause itself and its children to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal), any `write(2)` into the pipe will return `-1` with `errno` set to `EPIPE` ("broken pipe"). And sockets work the same as pipes in this regard.

Comment: Never attribute to malice that...